# MDX query not accepting date values

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx

I'm a SSAS newbie and i'm trying to query a cube to retrieve data against aome measure groups order by date. The date range i wish to specify in my query. The query I'm using is this:-

```
SELECT
{
    [Measures].[Measure1],
    [Measures].[Measure2],
    [Measures].[Measure3]
} 
ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY{
   [Date].[AllMembers]
         } 
ON ROWS
FROM (SELECT ( STRTOMEMBER('2/23/2013', CONSTRAINED) : 
STRTOMEMBER('3/1/2013', CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM   [MyCube])
```

However it gives me the following error

 **Query (10, 16) The restrictions imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag in the STRTOMEMBER function were violated.**

I tried removing the constrained keyword and then even strtomember function. But in each cases i got the following errors respectively

**Query (10, 16) The STRTOMEMBER function expects a member expression for the 1 argument. A string or numeric expression was used.**

and

**Query (10, 14) The : function expects a member expression for the 1 argument. A string or numeric expression was used.
**

I can understand from the last two errors that i need to include the constraint keyword. But can anyone tell me why this query wont execute?

Comment: SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Stock Entry Main Count], [Measures].[Quantity1], [Measures].[Quantity2] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Master Store].[Store Code].[Store Code].ALLMEMBERS * [Master SOS].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Stock Entry Main].[Textentrydate].[Textentrydate].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT { STRTOMEMBER(@FromStockEntryMainTextentrydate) : STRTOMEMBER(@ToStockEntryMainTextentrydate) } ON COLUMNS FROM [Testka])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string that you pass as the member expression must be a fully-qualified member name, or resolve to one. Use the same format as you did in the SELECT.

For example:

```
STRTOMEMBER('[Date].[2/23/2013]', CONSTRAINED)
```

Edit: I just noticed the syntax of your range select looks wrong -- you need to use `{...}`, not `(...)`.

```
SELECT { 
    STRTOMEMBER('2/23/2013', CONSTRAINED) : 
    STRTOMEMBER('3/1/2013', CONSTRAINED) }
```

Comment: Just noticed another potential problem with the range select. Updated the answer above.

Comment: It's still giving the same error :(. Cant understand what could be wrong, i mean i do have data for those dates in my cube.. I even tried in combinations like {} alongwhith '[Date].[2/23/2013]'. Still exactly the same error!

Comment: Just to be clear, the member name I used as an example was made up -- is that really the unique name in your cube? You need to construct the exact name, not a general date representation. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Its working fine now. Was a little problem with the syntax of member function.

Comment: I have below code but it still giving me same error SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Stock Entry Main Count], [Measures].[Quantity1], [Measures].[Quantity2] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Master Store].[Store Code].[Store Code].ALLMEMBERS * [Master SOS].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Stock Entry Main].[Textentrydate].[Textentrydate].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT { STRTOMEMBER(@FromStockEntryMainTextentrydate) : STRTOMEMBER(@ToStockEntryMainTextentrydate) } ON COLUMNS FROM [Testka])

Answer (score 1):

Please execute below script. 
Extract your date dimension attribute copy it by right clicking and paste it in STRTOMEMBER value.

It will works fine.

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] } ON COLUMNS 
 FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOMEMBER('[Date].[Date].&[20050701]')  : 
 STRTOMEMBER('[Date].[Date].&[20061007]') )  ON COLUMNS 
 FROM [Adventure Works])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM ( SELECT (
   STRTOMEMBER(@FromDateCalendarDate, CONSTRAINED) :
   STRTOMEMBER(@ToDateCalendarDate, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS
```

Comment: Please expound upon your answer